# ¿Cómo consultar y filtrar un archivo JSON alojado en MongoDB con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, mongodb

Tengo un archivo JSON que yo alojo en mango y me gustaria obtener algunos de sus elementos. Aqui esta el archivo

```
{
  "_id": "5de9483c65222ef002ad6135",
  "election": "local-min-2015",
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              5039258.279933322,
              5142586.1579948
            ],
            [
              5039615.847231327,
              5142411.105566747
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "1": {
          "Partido Popular": "50.64"
        },
        "2": {
          "Partido Socialista Obrero Espanol": "3.22"
        },
        "3": {
          "Unidos Podemos": "1.29"
        },
        "4": {
          "Ciudadanos": "26.18"
        },
        "5": {
          "Vox": "18.45"
        },
        "id": 96918,
        "parent_id": 96916,
        "common_id": "11.01",
        "common_name": "11.01",
        "has_children": true,
        "shape_type_id": 5,
        "shape_type_name": "Majoritarian District",
        "value": "No Data",
        "color": null,
        "title_location": "Majoritarian District: 11.01",
        "Total Voter Turnout (%)": 55.08
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              5039258.279933322,
              5142586.1579948
            ],
            [
              5039615.847231327,
              5142411.105566747
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "1": {
          "Partido Popular": "45.64"
        },
        "2": {
          "Partido Socialista Obrero Espanol": "7.22"
        },
        "3": {
          "Unidos Podemos": "2.29"
        },
        "4": {
          "Ciudadanos": "26.18"
        },
        "5": {
          "Vox": "18.45"
        },
        "id": 96919,
        "parent_id": 96916,
        "common_id": "11.01",
        "common_name": "11.01",
        "has_children": true,
        "shape_type_id": 5,
        "shape_type_name": "Majoritarian District",
        "value": "No Data",
        "color": null,
        "title_location": "Majoritarian District: 11.01",
        "Total Voter Turnout (%)": 55.08
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Y me gustaria obtener:

```
{
  "0": {
    "parties": [
      {
        "Partido Popular": 50.64
      },
      {
        "Partido Socialista Obrero Espanol": 3.22
      },
      {
        "Unidos Podemos": 1.29
      },
      {
        "Ciudadanos": 26.18
      },
      {
        "Vox": 18.45
      }
    ],
    "id": 96918
  },
  "1": {
    "parties": [
      {
        "Partido Popular": 45.64
      },
      {
        "Partido Socialista Obrero Espanol": 7.22
      },
      {
        "Unidos Podemos": 2.29
      },
      {
        "Ciudadanos": 26.18
      },
      {
        "Vox": 18.45
      }
    ],
    "id": 96919
  }
}
```

Hasta hoy intente obtener los "properties" pero obtenia un problema:

```
import pymongo
from bson.son import SON
import json

import os

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

db = client["Richmond"]

collection = db['Collection']

# select the documents where the field features contains the field 0
cursor = db.collection.find(
    {"_id": "5de9483c65222ef002ad613"},
    { "features": 1, "type": 0, "election": 0, "_id": 0 }
)

for doc in cursor:
    print(doc)
```

El cmd me devuelve:

```
(base) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Richmond\Mongo>python query_mongdb.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "query_mongdb.py", line 20, in <module>
    for doc in cursor:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1156, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1073, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 955, in __send_message
    address=self.__address)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1347, in _run_operation_with_response
    exhaust=exhaust)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1465, in _retryable_read
    return func(session, server, sock_info, slave_ok)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1341, in _cmd
    unpack_res)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\server.py", line 136, in run_operation_with_response
    _check_command_response(first)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 159, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la forma en que escribes la proyección de elementos que deseas incluir y excluir de tu consulta.

El error indica:

> Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.

Que traducido es:

> La Proyección no puede contener una mezcla de inclusión y exclusión.

Y es que estás mezclando inclusiones y exclusiones sobre los campos que deseas que sean devueltos por la consulta:

```
cursor = db.collection.find(
  {"_id": "5de9483c65222ef002ad613"},
  { "features": 1, "type": 0, "election": 0, "_id": 0 }  # <= aquí haces la mezcla.
)
```

De la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection) de MongoDB, sobre la cual se basa el driver de Mongo para `Python`, se puede leer lo siguiente: (traducción propia)

> Una proyección no puede especificar al mismo tiempo inclusión y exclusión, excepto para la exclusión del campo `_id`. En proyecciones que incluye campos explícitamente, el campo `_id` es el único campo que se puede excluir explícitamente.

Por lo tanto tu consulta debe ser:

```
cursor = db.collection.find(
  {"_id": "5de9483c65222ef002ad613"},
  { "features": 1, "_id": 0 }  # <= si sólo queremos el campo 'features'
)
```

En la consulta anterior, estamos incluyendo explícitamente el campo `features`, el resto de campos se entienden excluidos, con excepción del campo `_id` que siempre se incluye, y por lo tanto, es el único que podemos excluir explícitamente en la consulta.

Si deseáramos excluir sólo 1 campo (por ejemplo `type`) y dejar el resto de campos como incluidos, la consulta sería:

```
cursor = db.collection.find(
  {"_id": "5de9483c65222ef002ad613"},
  { "type": 0 }  # <= solo se excluye 'type'
)
```

No necesitamos incluir más nada, ya que al aparecer la exclusión sobre uno o más campos, los demás se sobreentienden incluidos.

Recuerda que el campo `_id` siempre se considera incluido, por lo tanto es el único campo que podemos excluir explícitamente aunque la consulta sea de inclusión.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.